# Higher Order Legendre Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, approximation, legendre-polynomials

What do higher order Legendre polynomials mean? When approximating a function by sum of Legendre polynomials, in which conditions one can ignore higher order terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they give more detail about the function